# Scala Slick pagination compiles, but crash on running

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework, pagination, slick

I have slick join query in a one to many relation

```
val query = for {
((u,a),j) <- users join address on(_.idUser === _.idUser) join
               jobs on(_._1.idUser == _.idUser)
} yield (u,a,j)

val res = db.run(query.groupBy(_._1.idUser).flatMap(_._2)
                  .drop((page - 1) * perPage).take(perPage).result)
```

I need to have unique users, that's why I am groupping by idUser first. The thing is the code compiles, but when I run I have a slick error:
"slick.SlickTreeExceptions: Unresolved monadic join: Non-Pure select clause in Bind s2"

Any help on how to achieve this pagination would be most appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I've figure it out! I've done this similar with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33633385/slick-3-how-to-drop-and-take-on-collections-with-some-relations)

Comment: May I know how you did it.

Answer (score 1):

`_._1.idUser == _.idUser` should be `_._1.idUser === _.idUser`

`SlickTreeException` is [thrown](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/master/slick/src/main/scala/slick/compiler/VerifySymbols.scala#L24-L25) when [monadic joins](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.0.0/queries.html#monadic-joins) are desugared to [applicative joins](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.0.0/queries.html#applicative-joins).

> Monadic joins are created with `flatMap`. They are theoretically more
>   powerful than applicative joins because the right-hand side may depend
>   on the left-hand side. However, this is not possible in standard SQL,
>   so Slick has to compile them down to applicative joins, which is
>   possible in many useful cases but not in all of them **(and there are
>   cases where it is possible in theory but Slick cannot perform the
>   required transformation yet)**. If a monadic join cannot be properly
>   translated, **it will fail at runtime**.

Can you change `.groupBy(_._1.idUser).flatMap(_._2)` with `.sortBy(_._1.idUser)`?